# Issues playing/ripping DVD on iMac

Tags: file-conversion, dvd

OS: Yosemite 10.10.4

So, I have a kids educational DVD I want to rip to have on my phone for commute time.  No problem in a DVD player.

On my Mac, DVD Player has it blotchy and large amount of artifacts.  I tried to use Handbrake to rip it, same issue - bad audio and huge video artifacts.  I tried to be clever and say "oh, it must be timing with DVD hardware, lets create a disk image with Disk Utility, mount it, and let Handbrake do the rip with the mounted drive instead" Nope, still has video artifacts and bad audio.

I searched here, nothing about artifacts, just DVD ripping tips.  Anyone else experienced this and figured something out?

Comment: Might be worth having a look at [Smart Converter](http://www.shedworx.com/smart-converter), freeware [There's a paid 'pro' version too but I don't know what extra that version does]

Answer (score 1):

You said that you tried to create an image but did you use DiskUtility?

Try to create new image of your DVD using DiskUtility. Save it to *.cdr file and **mount & play** or **burn** already created image to see the difference.